# Trigonometry and Reflex Angles?

Tags: trigonometry

I get $16/65$ for this question, when the answers say $56/65$. I'm guessing it's because of the reflex angles part:

If $A$ and $B$ are both reflex angles, and given $\cos A=3/5$ and $\tan B=12/5$, find the exact value of $\sin(A-B)$.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we are working with standard $3,4,5$ and $5,12,13$ triangles. It is therefore a question of taking care over the signs of all the trigonometric

A reflex angle $A$ has $\sin A \le 0$ - if in doubt sketch the curve.

So for the angles given we must have  $\sin A = -\frac 45$ and since $\tan B =\frac {\sin B}{\cos B}$ is positive, we must have $\cos B \lt 0$ so that $\sin B=-\frac {12}{13}$ and $\cos B=-\frac 5{13}$.

These can be plugged into the standard formula $\sin (A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$, again taking care over signs.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use [all sin tan cos rule](http://www.math-only-math.com/all-sin-tan-cos-rule.html)

As $180^\circ<A<360^\circ,\cos A=\frac35>0\implies 270^\circ<A<360^\circ\implies \sin A<0$

$\sin A=-\sqrt{1-\cos^2A}$

As $180^\circ<B<360^\circ,\tan B=\frac{12}5>0\implies 180^\circ<B<270^\circ\implies \cos B<0\iff \sec B<0$

So, $\displaystyle\sec B=-\sqrt{1+\tan^2B}$ and $\sin B=\displaystyle\frac{\tan B}{\sec B}$

Now   $\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$